# how to know if you need to git fetch using terminal

Tags: git, github

How can I determine if the remote repo is different to my local repo?

I know i can do

```
git pull
```

**or**

```
git fetch
```

then

```
git pull
```

But I'm looking for a command I can type in terminal that checks if the remote repo is diff from my local one?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of what `fetch` does. It's required to see what's on the remote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git fetch` will be your command. If you see the pointers being fetched then something was changed. `git status` will tell you if they are different, too, but if you don't call `git fetch` you won't be able to see if the remote changed.

Comment: It only updates the references to the remote branches. That's usually harmless and desirable. It doesn't merge.

Comment: So i should make `git fetch` part of my workflow? New to git.

Comment: @AdamJarvis Your workflow should tolerate being out of date with remotes. You should check for updates when you're at a point you feel you need to update, like when a feature is nearing completion, or you know a major change has happened in your upstream branch, or it's just been a while. Most importantly, you should be working in feature branches to increase your isolation from other's changes.

Comment: @AdamJarvis really you should be developing on a branch. When you are ready to merge your changes into the master you should update your local master. Merge into your development branch, Test, and then merge the now up-to-date code with your changes into the master. If you are developing a change while others are doing the same you may wish to merge the master into your branch periodically to ensure your not conflicting with anyone else's work.